# word 2003 VBA code not working in word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

Friends,
I am trying to disable the display alerts while using printout command. The code isn't working as I get the runtime error like'read only', 'word converter','invalid reference type'. I would like to suppress all those errors. My code is below
Could you confirm how to code the same word in 2007, this works okay in word 2003.

```
    If optCentral.Value = False Then
        Set oPrint = GetObject(lbxResults.List(varLoop))
    End If
End If

If optCentral.Value = True Then
    'do nothing, already copied
ElseIf optPtrOver.Value = True Then
    With oPrint
        'Store existing print settings
        bValueStoreUFAP = .Application.Options.UpdateFieldsAtPrint
        bValueStoreULAP = .Application.Options.UpdateLinksAtPrint
        bValueStoreDisplayAllerts = .Application.DisplayAlerts

        'Change print settings, stops unwanted pop-up boxes
        .Application.Options.UpdateFieldsAtPrint = False
        .Application.Options.UpdateLinksAtPrint = False
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

        'Print document
        .PrintOut copies:=varCopies

        'Restore original print settings
        .Application.Options.UpdateFieldsAtPrint = bValueStoreUFAP
        .Application.Options.UpdateLinksAtPrint = bValueStoreULAP
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = bValueStoreDisplayAllerts

        .Saved = True
        .Close
```

Comment: Check your Library References in the VBA editor.  They may need to match your 2003 version.

Comment: If that doesn't clear it up, then give more information.   What precise errors occur, and at what precise points in the code?

Comment: thanks.I would like to suppress the error if the document is 'readonly' which stops the document prints in bulk.The error happens at .printout copies:=varcopies line.

Comment: At this point I would recommend first that you provide the err number (if there is one) and exact text.  That way I can run a search on Google for you.  :-)  Second, just wondering if the document and folder location are set as read-only in the operating system and that is the cause of the problem (though seems unlikely since the problem arose with new version of Word.

Comment: I'm assuming the type of oPrint is a `Word.Document`. From the MSDN reference for `PrintOut` for Word [2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb237242(v=office.12).aspx), all the arguments are optional (so it's not because of some argument you aren't passing) and the `Copies` argument is still there, just like in [2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220363(v=office.11).aspx). What error are you seeing?

Comment: If your code isn't working, the solution is not to turn off alerts. That's like putting on earplugs in order to drive a car whose engine is making odd noises.

Comment: There isn't any specific error. My code prints documents in a folder, when one of the document is readonly then warning message pops up which stops the printing. So I would like to suppress all such errors. The displayalerts = false not working because i get the warning message..

Comment: Exactly what does the message say?

Comment: Also, what does this line in your question mean: **I get the runtime error like'read only', 'word converter','invalid reference type'**? Are you seeing all this in the same error?

Comment: All errors in same line '.printout copies:=varcopies but not all errors together. I am printing in bulk so don't care whether document is readonly or not. so i have to ignore the error and print. My requirement is to ignore all types of runtime error and pop ups to ignore and print otherwise it stops the printing.

Comment: The error is 5180 word cannot open this document. I want to suppress this error because am interested to print only the content

Comment: Perhaps try ignoring all errors - `On Error Resume Next` at the beginning of the `Sub`. Or add an error handler within the `Sub` which contains a `Resume Next` statement, which will allow you to track errors even if you decide to ignore them. If the issue is that the document is readonly, perhaps you should consider saving a read/writeable copy and printing that instead.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the VBA code block (`Sub` or `Function`), make the first line this:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

This may allow you to do what you want.

It is poor practice, in general.  It would be a sloppy and dangerous fix.  VBA provides good tools for error-handling, and you apply those.  The consequences of suppressed error reporting are big.

That said, using the `Resume Next` instruction is actually fine for initial trouble shooting.  Depending entirely on your situation, it may even be an adequate solution.

If you still receive the error, then you are dealing with an issue in the Word document or the file structure.  I think that's likely.  In that case, you'll be a big step forward in solving the problem.  Just don't forget to remove the `Resume Next` instruction.